# When are sections.xml files considered?

Tags: magento2

I have the following XML file `sections.xml` at the following path:

> Magento2Dir/app/code/vendor/module/etc/frontend/section.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="customproduct/manage/add">
        <section name="cart" />
    </action>
</config>
```

I have a bit of code on a page which sends the product ids and quantities to a controller which adds the product to the cart (the products do get added to the cart).

This does not update the mini-cart. If I add another product using the method for default products (Standard add to cart) then it works and the mini-cart is updated.

What is the minimum I require for the mini-cart to load changes?

**Including via AJAX**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that I was hitting it with an ajax request to a relative url - the section will only update in version 2.1.4 if an absolute url is used.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file in ModuleName/etc/frontend sections.xml your miniCart will Update.

Comment: <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="ModuleName/customer/addtocart">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I already have?